# Is there a formula for the largest readable font size?

Tags: page-layout, typefaces, font-design

I'm working on a project about "creating rules" about design and text sizes in a layout... even when you do not have the size of the layout.

My co-worker and I can't agree on the largest text size to use. It gets complicated when our designers try to explain to our co-workers what motivates our choice for the text size and proportions.

I was planning to create a formula based on distance, visual range and size of my layout (once I know the size).

**Is there a formula designers use in similar situation or any guideline that can be applied (in general) to any layout, no matter the size of the layout?**

Comment: Can you please specify what kind of application and readability we are talking about? In theory, I can read text, even when a single letter fills my entire field of vision – it’s just not very comfortable.